# Nested Model Forms -- How do you create an object through an association if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From Ryan Bates's [episode about nested model forms](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), I was able to create a project with `concerts`, `bands` and `performances` that they play. I can add performances to a new concert or when I edit a concert. That's fairly simple and straightforward when I follow his tutorial.

`performances` belongs to `bands` and `performances` belongs to `concerts`. A performance will list the band playing and the time starting/ending. Bands only have a string column for its name.

When I create a new concert and add a whole slew of performances, I'd like to, at the same time, be able to create the `band` objects if they don't already exist. Otherwise, the user has the added step(s) of creating those objects, which would be tedious.

How, through `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or some other useful Rails feature, can I do this? I am using Rails 2.3.8

Here are my associations:

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :performances
  has_many :concerts, :through => :performances
end

class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :performances
  has_many :bands, :through => :performances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :performances, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :concert
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails can handle this for you, you just need to make sure you pass in the params the right way (which multiple nested forms should do for you)

```
class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :performances
  has_many :bands, :through => :performances

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :performances
end


class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :concert
  has_many :bands

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bands
end


class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :performance
end
```

Your `params` hash should look like this:

```
{
  :concert => {
    :performances_attributes => [
      {
        :bands_attributes => [
          {
            :name => "test u"
          }],
        :name=>"test p"
      }], 
    :name=>"test"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right; I was just creating the forms incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You `build` new blank instances of the association that you want to create. In the case of a `belongs_to`, the method to build the association instance is `"build_#{association_name}"` so if you wanted to create a new band via a performance that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :band` you would initialize a blank band in your controller method:

```
class PerformancesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @performance = Performance.new       # You're building 
                                         # the performance to create
    @performance.build_band              # You're building
                                         # the band to create
  end
end
```

The build method for has_many associations is `"#{association_name}.build`, so for a band that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :performances`:

```
class BandsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @band = Band.new
    3.times { @band.performances.build }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the build method noted above for the fields to show up in your form.  Following is how you'd set up your form.

```
<%= form_for @concert do |cf| %>  
  <%= cf.label :name %>  
  <%= cf.text_field :name %>  
  <%= cf.fields_for :performances do |pf| do %>  
     <%= pf.label :some_attr %>  
     ...  
     <%= pf.fields_for :bands do |bf| %>  
          <%= bf.label ... %>  
     <%end>  
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried this in a custom rails app just now and couldn't get it to work. The params hash was malformed. It had :concert => {:name => ..., :performances => {}...} instead of :concert => {:name => ..., :performances_attributes => [{}]}